# For Loop is skipping every other line while searching ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have an array list of sequential Integers from 10 to 100. I generate a random number (say 50) and then I want to remove all numbers that have a "5" in the 10's position- all integers from 50 - 59.

```
public static void updateMyGuess() {

 ArrayList<Integer> possibles = new ArrayList <Integer>();

 for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
   possibles.add(i); 
    }

 int guess = 50; //my guess is generated by another method. Not listed here
 int tens = guess / 10 % 10;
 int x;

 for ( int i = 0; i < possibles.size(); i++) {
   x = possibles.get(i);
   if (x / 10 % 10 == tens) {
     possibles.remove(i);
 } 
}
```

For some reason this will only remove every other value from the ArrayList in the 50's: 50, 52, 54... 58. Why is this? And what can I change to make it take out all the 50s?

Comment: Either use an iterator (best approach) or search your list from backwards (simplest hack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `Iterator` as suggested by @nlloyd is a better solution here.

However, there might be an occasion where (for whatever reason) you can't use an `Iterator` (e.g. you are working in a language or library that doesn't provide iterators). The simple solution is to iterate in reverse:

```
for ( int i = possibles.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

It isn't clear why you need to add items to the list in the first place if you are going to remove them again immediately:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> possibles = new ArrayList <Integer>();
 int guess = 50; //my guess is generated by another method. Not listed here
 int tens = guess / 10 % 10;

 for (int x = 10; x < 100; x++) {
   if (x / 10 % 10 != tens) {
     possibles.add(x);
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

After you remove the element at `[i]`, the one at `[i+1]` (and all the ones after) moves up one space. The old `[i+1]` now occupies the element at `[i]`, so when `i` increments you skip the one that moved up.

Answer (score 2):

As Jim mentioned, you're mutating the list while going over it, effectively skipping over items.

Use an iterator instead of a for loop. Iterators are made to remove elements while you are traversing the list.

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = possibilities.iterator()
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   x = iter.next();
   if (x / 10 % 10 == tens) {
     iter.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In java 8 ArrayList has a remove if method as well.
[for more examples on how to use removeIf](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/arraylist/arraylist_removeif.php)

```
ArrayList<Integer> possibles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        possibles.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println(possibles);
    int guess = 50; // my guess is generated by another method. Not listed
            // here
    int tens = guess / 10 % 10;
    int x;
    // removes all the elements for which removeIf returns true
    possibles.removeIf(new Predicate<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Integer arg0) {
             return arg0 / 10 % 10 == tens;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(possibles);
```